# How to run Java file on Google Cloud VM?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I want to run a java file on a VM instance I've created in Google Cloud under Compute Engine. However, it's not clear how to do this. I pressed SSH and uploaded the java file but I dont know what to do after that. It doesn't allow me to start the VM. Please, does anyone know how to do this? Run a simple java file on Google Cloud's VM?

Comment: If you feel like my answer has solved your question you can always mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't SSH into a VM that hasn't been started so the fact that you can SSH into the VM implicitly means it has been started.

If the `.java` file is accessible to the VM and the relevant JDK has been installed on your VM, you can compile and then it run like you'd run any other Java program. You can use `javac` for the compilation and `java` to run the compiled `.class` file. You can take a look at [this article](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html) for more info on how to do that.

Comment: So I can treat the SSH pop up like a command prompt and use the commands necessary to run my java file?

Comment: I uploaded my Java file via the SSH prompt. I tried to run commands to run the java file but obviously it has no reference to a JDK so that's where I'm stuck

Comment: I have no idea how to install the JDK on the VM!

Comment: @sidharthramanan Depending on your OS the installation instructions will be different. It should be easy to google the CLI instructions needed by searching for "installation JDK {JDK VERSION) command line {YOUR OS}". E.g. "installation jdk 7 command line ubuntu"